# Is there a way to read a command line dictionary or json arguments in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read the command line argument as json format, or the key:value pair and I want to use the Key as variable name in the program and value is equal to variable value, for example, if user submitted, rank:1, than my program will use rank as variable name and number 1 as its value, that is rank = 1 in program.
Could someone please help me to achieve this using multiple key:value pairs as command line arguments.

Also is there a way to change the field separator from space to comma or anything else?

Comment: It’s a terrible idea to use variable variables. Why not keep it in a dict?

Comment: @deceze, sorry my main Idea of the question is, how can I pass the dictionary in python through command line arguments like { 'name': 'Rafiq', 'age' : '23' } like that. for example, python test.py { 'name': 'Rafiq', 'age' : '23' }

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/howto/argparse.html) library: it should help you to achieve your goal by declaring keywords as command line arguments.

This library is very useful and offers a lot of possibilities.